# WP7 LongListSelector : Color of the semi-transparent background

Tags: windows-phone-7, longlistselector

There is any way to change the background color of the mask semi-transparent shown when you tap on header made by a LongListSelector?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom GropItemsPanel Template. It covers the screen.

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector  ItemsSource="{Binding Shows}" GroupItemsPanel="{StaticResource LongListItemsPanelTemplateCustom}" ></toolkit:LongListSelector>


<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="LongListItemsPanelTemplateCustom"><StackPanel Background="Red"/></ItemsPanelTemplate>
```